# Group data by 2 columns and do calculation in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data.frame

```
> ID=c("S","B","S","S","B","S","S","S","B","B","S")     #"S" means Sell, "B" means Buy
> quant=c(3,2,5,1,2,10,4,4,17,6,6)
> time=c(1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6)
> test=data.frame(ID,quant,time)
    ID quant time
  1  S     3    1
  2  B     2    2
  3  S     5    3
  4  S     1    3
  5  B     2    4
  6  S    10    4
  7  S     4    5
  8  S     4    5
  9  B    17    5
  9  B    6     6
  9  S    6     6
```

I need to calculate the net position of each time, so that my final output would be

```
    ID quant time
  1  S     3    1
  2  B     2    2
  3  S     6    3    #Sell 5+1=6
  4  S     8    4    #Sell 10-2=8
  5  B     9    5    #Buy 17-4-4=9
  6  B     0    6    #this row is optional because the position is 0 so I don't need it
```

I think I need to group the data.frame first by time and then by ID, but then how can I perform the calculation of net position? I've tried to use `aggregate` but it seems it's only valid for grouping by one column? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another idea, that might look a bit fragile, but seems valid for the specific case:

```
tmp = diff(xtabs(quant ~ ID + time, test))
data.frame(ID = c(ifelse(tmp > 0, "S", "B")), 
           time = colnames(tmp), 
           quant = c(abs(tmp)))
#  ID time quant
#1  S    1     3
#2  B    2     2
#3  S    3     6
#4  S    4     8
#5  B    5     9
#6  B    6     0
```

And a classic approach in base R:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(test, test$time), 
               function(x) { 
                  s = sum(x[["quant"]][x[["ID"]] == "S"])
                  b = sum(x[["quant"]][x[["ID"]] == "B"])
                  data.frame(time = x$time[1], 
                             quant = abs(s - b),
                             ID = if(s > b) "S" else "B")
               }))
#  time quant ID
#1    1     3  S
#2    2     2  B
#3    3     6  S
#4    4     8  S
#5    5     9  B
#6    6     0  B
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, list(quant = sum(quant[ID == "B"]) - sum(quant[ID == "S"])),
            by = time][, list(ID = ifelse(quant > 0, "B", "S"), quant = abs(quant), time)]

#    ID quant time
# 1:  S     3    1
# 2:  B     2    2
# 3:  S     6    3
# 4:  S     8    4
# 5:  B     9    5
# 6:  S     0    6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- test %>% 
      group_by(time) %>%
      summarise(quant = sum(quant[ID == "B"]) - sum(quant[ID == "S"])) %>% 
      mutate(ID = c("S", "B")[(quant >= 0) + 1], quant = abs(quant))

#   time quant ID
# 1    1     3  S
# 2    2     2  B
# 3    3     6  S
# 4    4     8  S
# 5    5     9  B
# 6    6     0  B
```

---

What does `c("S", "B")[(quant >= 0) + 1]` mean?

- The command `(quant >= 0)` creates a logical vector indicating whether `quant` is equal or greater than 0.
- In the next step, 1 is added to this vector. If mathematical operators are used with logical vectors, `FALSE` is transformed to `0` and `TRUE` is transformed to `1`. Hence this command results in a vector of 1s and 2s.
- This vector is used as an index vector for `c("S", "B")` and therefore results in character vector of `"S"`s and `"B"`s.

Comment: @ Sven can you please explain this step c("S", "B")[(quant >= 0) + 1]

Comment: @koundy I added an explanation.

Comment: @Seven thanks a lot.. even im trying to answer using dplyr but stuck at that step.